# Functional Expectation

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra

Problem: Let  $X$  be distributed over the set  $\Bbb N$  of non-negative integers, with pmf: $$P(X=i)=\frac{\alpha}{2^i}$$

- $\alpha$
- $E[X]$

For $Y=X$ mod $3$, find:

- $P(Y=1)$
- $E[Y]$

---

- I will assume $\alpha=1$ for now to set the stage althought is there a way to find this value rather than assume?
- Assuming this is simlar to an infinite expectation that starts with Basel problem: $$\sum_{i=0}^\infty \frac{1}{i^2}=\frac{\pi^2}{6}$$
  $$\frac{6}{\pi^2}\sum_{i=0}^\infty \frac{1}{i^2}=1$$
  $$p_i = \frac{6}{\pi^2}\cdot\frac{1}{i^2}$$
  $$E[X]=\sum_{i=0}^\infty i \cdot p_i=\frac{6}{\pi^2}\sum_{i=0}^\infty \frac{1}{i}=\infty$$
  However, just not certain.

For the "$Y=X$ mod $3$" part I don't even know what that means.  Does that mean $Y=X+3$?
Thus I don't know how to answer the rest of them without understanding what "mod $3$" means.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic may be helpful to explain the last part. For the first part, you don't need to assume anything about $\alpha$. Since it is a PMF it will satisfy the properties of a PMF: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_mass_function

Comment: So is $\alpha=1$?

Comment: You need to prove what value $\alpha$ takes by using the properties of a PMF: In particular $\sum_i P(X = i) = 1$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

0. 

In order to guarantee that $p_i=\frac{\alpha}{2^i}$ is a distribution, we have that:

$$\sum_{i=0}^{+\infty} p_i = 1 \Rightarrow \\\alpha \sum_{i=0}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{2^i} = \alpha \frac{1}{1 - \frac{1}{2}} = 2 \alpha = 1 \Rightarrow \alpha = \frac{1}{2}.$$

1.
$$P(Y=1) = P(X ~\text{mod}~ 3 = 1) = \sum_{i : i ~\text{mod}~ 3 = 1}\frac{\alpha}{2^i}.$$

But all $i$ such that $i ~\text{mod}~ 3 = 1$ can be rewritten as:

$$i = 3j + 1,$$

for $j \geq 0.$ Hence:

$$P(Y=1)  = \sum_{j=0}^{+\infty} \frac{\alpha}{2^{3j + 1}} = \frac{\alpha}{2}\sum_{j=0}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{8^{j} } = \frac{\alpha}{2}\frac{1}{1 - \frac{1}{8}} = \frac{4}{7}\alpha = \frac{2}{7} .$$

2.

$$\mathbb{E}[Y=1] = \sum_{j=0}^{+\infty} (3j + 1)\frac{\alpha}{2^{3j + 1}} = \sum_{j=0}^{+\infty} \frac{3j\alpha}{2^{3j + 1}} + \sum_{j=0}^{+\infty} \frac{\alpha}{2^{3j + 1}} = \\
=\frac{3\alpha}{2}\sum_{j=0}^{+\infty} j\left(\frac{1}{8}\right)^j + \frac{4}{7}\alpha = \frac{3\alpha}{16}\sum_{j=0}^{+\infty} j\left(\frac{1}{8}\right)^{j-1} + \frac{4}{7}\alpha =\\
 = \frac{3\alpha}{16}\frac{1}{\left(1 - \frac{1}{8}\right)^2}  + \frac{4}{7}\alpha   = \frac{3\alpha}{16}\frac{64}{49}  + \frac{4}{7}\alpha = \frac{12\alpha}{49} + \frac{28 \alpha}{49} = \frac{40}{49}\alpha = \frac{20}{49}.
  $$